# Lifetimes for traits

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

Let there is some struct:

```rust
struct ResourceData { }
```

We can create its list:

```rust
pub struct ResourceList
{
    pub v: Vec<ResourceData>,
}
```

but if I add a level of indirection:

```rust
pub trait Resource<'a> {
    fn data(&self) -> &'a ResourceData;
    fn data_mut(&mut self) -> &'a mut ResourceData;
}
```

then I am messed:

```rust
pub struct ResourceList2<R: Resource<'a>> // What should be 'a?
{
    pub v: Vec<R>,
}
```

What should be `'a`?

`'a` could be the lifetime of the vector, but if an element is removed, the lifetime of the references shorten, because references break. So, accordingly my understanding, `'a` isn't the lifetime of the vector.

Comment: Is `'a` not just another generic parameter to `ResourceList2`?

Comment: @BallpointBen I think no, because it is about the lifetime of an item `v` inside `ResourceList2`, not of `ResourceList2` itself.

Comment: @BallpointBen Lifetimes of different items may be different: Insert a vector element, it lives for some time; then clear the vector and insert another element, it lives for another time.

Comment: Oh, you may be looking for HRTB https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html

Comment: @BallpointBen Maybe. How to use HRTB in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Resource should not have a lifetime argument, but instead just use elided lifetimes:

```rust
pub trait Resource {
    fn position(&self) -> &ResourceData;
    fn position_mut(&mut self) -> &mut ResourceData;
}
```

After understanding this, the question disappears, just:

```rust
pub struct ResourceList2<R: Resource> // What should be 'a?
{
    pub v: Vec<R>,
}
```

Comment: Elided lifetimes are not "special" in any way. They're just a shorthand for a normal generic lifetimes, but not on the trait but instead on the method: `fn position<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a ResponseData`.